# Creating an inverted index in Python

Tags: python, performance

Here is the code I have written to create an inverted index dictionary for a set of documents:

```
inv_indx = {i:[] for i in corpus_dict}
for word in corpus_dict:
    for i in range(len(docs)):
        if word in docs[i]:
            inv_indx[word].append(i)
```

`docs` is a list of sets of the words in various documents:

```
[{'once','upon','a','time',...},{'lorum','ipsum','time'...},...]
```

`corpus_dict` is a set of all the words that appear in any of the documents:

```
{'once','upon','a','time','lorum','ipsum',...}
```

`inv_index` becomes a dictionary with each word in the corpus_dict as a key for a list of the document ids that contain that word:

```
{'once':[0],'time':[0,1],...}
```

The problem is this becomes very slow if the number of documents gets too big. How can I make this code more efficient?

Answer (score 5):

### Suggestions

- You check all words in all documents. Try iterate only over `docs` (without unnecessary checks)
- instead of create empty `inv_indx = {i:[] for i in corpus_dict}` you can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/librar/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

### Code

```
from collections import defaultdict

inv_indx = defaultdict(list)
for idx, text in enumerate(docs):
    for word in text:
        inv_indx[word].append(idx)
```

Comment: Wow that was so much faster. The defaultdict doesn't seem to have much impact on the perfomance though so I'll leave that out